# word 2013 - creating a report based on column checkmarks

Tags: microsoft-word, report

I created a checksheet with yes/no columns.  Is there a way to auto-report all of the items and comments that i checked "no" on a summary/report page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Form in Word. With a Form you tag or identify the various response points and then that data can be treated as a data source and the responses can be extracted to Excel or Access for reporting or other purposes.

First, you have to create a form. This is a "normal" document but you're going to use Controls rather than just fields or text boxes.

Here's in-depth instructions: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-fillable-form-39a58412-107e-426b-a10b-ac44937e3a9f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

But the basics are:

1. Enable the **Developer** ribbon.
2. In the **Developer** tab, in the **Controls** section, click **Design Mode**.
3. Insert the appropriate **Controls** to build your form.
4. Set the **Properties** for the controls so that you can easily identify the data and later extraction easy.
5. Set **Protection** on the document so that only the fields you want to be edited by users can be edited.

Now that you've got a form, sent it out, and received it back completed, you can extract the data.

1. Open a returned form, go to **File** > **Options** > **Advanced** > **Preserve Fidelity...** and enable **Save form data as delimited text file**.
2. Open **File** > **Save As** and save as the suggested text file.
3. Open this file in Excel.

You could use Macros to automate this capability for a large number of forms if you desire.